# Mesos master configuration error: Failed to load unknown flag

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mesos, mesosphere

I'm running mesos 0.20 master node under Ubuntu 14.04. All configuration options I keep in `/etc/default/mesos-master`. I have a problem with `MESOS_CREDENTIALS` variable. It points to an existing and accessible file with a whitespace separated list of login/password pairs.

File `/etc/default/mesos-master`

```
MESOS_AUTHENTICATE=TRUE
MESOS_AUTHENTICATE_SLAVES=TRUE 
MESOS_CREDENTIALS=/etc/mesos-master/credentials.txt
```

File `/etc/mesos-master/credentials.txt`

```
login1 password1
login2 password2
```

I'm receiving an error on `mesos-master` start:

```
Failed to load unknown flag 'credentials.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesos does not uses a consolidated configuration file. All configuration options you want to set you can set either through environment variables or by creating "option" files in Mesos config directory (`/etc/mesos-master/` in my case).

For example if you want to change `--work_dir` option you can do one of the below:
  * create a file `/etc/mesos-master/work_dir` containing some value
  * set environment variable `MESOS_WORK_DIR`.

Any files in `/etc/mesos-master/` named other than known Mesos options lead to the "unknown flag" error.

See http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when Mesos is parsing the flags, so it has nothing to do with the contents of the file, and more to do with the syntax of expressing the flag. I can't see anything obviously wrong with what you're doing. You could try wrapping the value in "quotes", or test it out by running `mesos-master` directly on the command-line with the environment variable set manually.

Comment: I took another look at this, and you're actually storing your credentials in `/etc/mesos-master` which is another location where Mesos looks for command-line flags. So in addition to reading the `MESOS_CREDENTIALS` env variable to look for the credentials in that file, it's also trying to interpret `/etc/mesos-master/credentials.txt` as a `--credentials.txt` flag (not `--credentials`). To fix this, just move the credentials.txt file to another location, like `~/credentials.txt` or `/tmp/credentials.txt`